# How can i refresh Token using fuelsdk for php?

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

Here is the error messsage

> status:   code: 500  message: q0:FailedAuthentication The security
>   token could not be authenticated or authorized ---> A critical error
>   has occurred and has caused an authentication failure. The error has
>   been logged. Please try again and if the issue persists please contact
>   customer support. ---> SOAP Authorization failed for Oauth token:
>   08Scb50-JSpRnb-KOu0zLx-TWEhOiHjX2ksyYGVpxKzFxZDOFz7l5mibED7WCdHd7oI9jwNygouQUhMJ4U8-M3EqEs0_gZzaidaaH6Fgv7BMcTS7-Ik57Y9i1WI0R28nA9RMKK367OMIX4PaSTvH2a-50whfI02zQrXZ3C9ZuHjtLXKMz-tw1XKy5OrXqwQ1E.
>   Reason: Expired.)

Anyone could help on this?

Comment: What are you doing to get this error?  The SDK is supposed to refresh the token for you, so I'm not exactly sure what's happening. When does this happen for you?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error related to the token expiring. Can you confirm what SDK you had downloaded?