# ExactTarget TriggeredSend Throwing 'Token Expired' Error

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to use the [FuelSDK for ruby](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby) to fire off triggered sends.  I've registed my app at code.exacttarget.com and using [this page](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby/blob/master/samples/sample-triggeredsend.rb) as a guide, I'm able to successfully make most of the API calls listed.  The one exectption is the triggered send call.  I receive this error:

> The security token could not be authenticated or authorized ---> A critical error has occurred and has caused an authentication failure. The error has been logged. Please try again and if the issue persists please contact customer support. ---> SOAP Authorization failed for Oauth token: . Reason: Expired.

I saw a [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/26955/how-can-i-refresh-token-using-fuelsdk-for-php) which mentioned that SDK should take care of refreshing the token, but there was no accepted answer, so that may be bogus.  Any idea why I'm getting this error?

UPDATE:
After the error above mysterioulsy stopped appearing, the following error appeared.

> raw: !ruby/object:Savon::Response ...

```
xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Results>
        <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>Requested value 'APIObject' was not found.</StatusMessage>
        <NewID>0</NewID>
    </Results>
    <RequestID>fd99c8a7-da27-4138-a2e4-6fcb16281d7e</RequestID>
    <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
</CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've found some posts that suggest the problem is caused by Savon 2.2.3, but I have checked and verified that the gem is currently using 2.2.0.

To get the above error in the response, I follow instructions like this:

```
https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby/blob/master/samples/sample-triggeredsend.rb#L97-L110
```

Comment: This is a tad bizarre.  I'll try and sit down to see what's up.

Comment: Ok - sounds like a couple people are hitting this. I'm investigating to understand what's up.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Haven't heard anything back - testing seems to work for me. Is there a time frame when you get this back or anything? Without being able to reproduce, not sure I can do anything else for you at this point. If I hear anything else Ill let you know.

Comment: Getting a different error now.  Guess that's progress, though it doesn't say much for the Exact Target API's reliability.

Comment: Can you add the current error?

Comment: Can you also show what you are calling in your code to get that error?

Comment: Yep.  I've added that info above.